# com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of

Tags: java, json, jackson, java-money

I am creating spring web application and trying  to add new Entity with Money data(javamoney.moneta). Here is code:

```java
@Column(name = FLD_MONEY, unique = false, nullable = true)
private FastMoney money;

private String currencyUnit;
 
public AbstractClient() {
}

public AbstractClient(String clientId, String name, String email, String password, String roles, BigDecimal money, String currencyUnit) {
    this.currencyUnit=currencyUnit;
    this.clientId = clientId;
    this.name = name;
    this.money=FastMoney.of(money, Monetary.getCurrency(this.currencyUnit));
    this.email = email;
    this.password = hashPassword(password);
    this.active=true;
    this.roles=roles;
}
```

Added to table a column money and data will be filled with FastMoney. FastMoney is creating inside of constructor from BigDecimal money and String currencyUnit.

When I try to save with API endpoint with json body I have this issue:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException:
> Cannot construct instance of org.javamoney.moneta.FastMoney(no Creators, like default constructor, exist): no int/Int-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from Number value (32)

````
Here is JSON:

```json
{
   
    "money": 32,
    "currencyUnit": "EUR",
    "clientId": "Berik7182",
    "name": "Berik",
    "email": "berik@gmail.com",
    "password": "Berik123",
    "active": true,
    "roles": "ROLE_USER",
    "location": "Pecs",
    "pwcons": 30.0
    
}
````

What should I do?

Comment: `FastMoney` does have an empty constructor too? It's possible to pass `FastMoney` to the `AbstractClient` constructor?

Comment: @Josemy Thanks for comment, FastMoney doesn't have an empty constructor , I can't change file (read-only) and what do you mean with possible to pass?

Answer (score 0):

I did mistake, when I wrote money in JSON I wanted to put integer but system thought I am writing FastMoney. So I just created another int and changed name.